# Android Create Layered drawable in XML

Tags: android, user-interface

I would like to create a drawable in XML that should include:

1. image drawable
2. color drawable

The color drawable provides white transparent color. So, as a result we would have image with some white transparent layer on top.

I have tried to use LayerDrawable, but it fails to be created during application launch:

```
<LayerDrawable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <BitmapDrawable android:src="@drawable/button_play" />
     <ColorDrawable android:color="#80FFFFFF"/>
</LayerDrawable>
```

Could you please advice what is wrong here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the [Android documentation for LayerDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html):

> It can be defined in an XML file with
>   the <layer-list> element. Each
>   Drawable in the layer is defined in a
>   nested <item>.